# jquery , return false on submit doesnt work

Tags: jquery, submit, return

guys I'm getting crazy I don't understand why this doesn't work (it always did!)

```
        //add new folder
        $("#add_folder_form").submit(function(event){

            var folder_name = $(this).find([name="folder_name"]).val();
            var post_string = "folder_name="+folder_name+"&path="+path;
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url: "/admin/controllers/add_new_folder,php",
                data : post_string,
                success: function(response){

                    if (response){
                        event.preventDefault();
                     }
                     else {
                        event.preventDefault();
                     }
                }
            })


event.preventDefault();
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<form  id="add_folder_form" action="" method="post">
  New folder  <input style="width: 400px" name="folder_name" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="add_folder_form_send" value="save"/>
</form>
```

I also tried to use `click` on **#add_folder_form_send** and using return false; at the bottom of the function. It always submits!

Comment: what's the point of the if(response) if you do the same in both cases anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$('selector').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   ....// your ajax code here...
   return false;
})
```

because by the time you hit the preventDefault(); the page has already reloaded for you ... and it's too late to carry on any scripting actions...

Comment: the problem was find([name="folder_name"]) that apparently is incorrect

Comment: oh yes should be "find("[name=folder_name]")"... but still you should use event.preventDefault(); the first thing :) I have never seen so many errors in so little script lol :) but good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Is you javascript throwing any errors (check the console - set it to break on errors)?

This line looks pretty suspect (comma instead of dot)

```
url: "/admin/controllers/add_new_folder,php",
```

Answer (score 1):

u add ',' change to '.' in folowing text `add_new_folder,php`   `add_new_folder.php`

Comment: thats a good point but he says that he can't prevent the browser from submitting the form... :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because of this:

```
/admin/controllers/add_new_folder,php
```

... replace the comma with a dot, which will give you this:

```
/admin/controllers/add_new_folder.php
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return false;
```

instead of

```
preventDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return function(event){event.preventDefault();}/*return false*/
```